# What is an elegant solution to save small configuration data with Ionic 3?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

What is an elegant solution to save small configuration data?

Currently I save my data with the Files API. But this seems to me for small config data rather unclean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/). You can easily store your key/value pairs there.